# When I try to print out my array I get "0x7ffeedcf3a60" as my output

Tags: c++

I'm unsure why this occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int M,N;
int const ROW = 4;
int const COLUMN = 3;
int twoDimensional[4][3];

cout << "Welcome to the Matrix Calculator!" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Please enter a " << ROW << "x" << COLUMN << " matrix: " << endl;
cout << endl;
for (M = 0; M < 4; M++) {
    cout << endl;
    for (N = 0; N < 3; N++){
        cout << "Enter Row " << M + 1 << " Column " << N + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> twoDimensional[M][N];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you please show how you are outputting your array? Note that simply doing

```
cout<<twoDimensional;
```

outputs the **address** of the array. Try

```
for (M = 0; M < 4; M++) {
    for (N = 0; N < 3; N++){
        cout << twoDimensional[M][N]<<" ";  
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This code outputs the numerical value of the elements.